.org directive outside section is OK when using GNU AS assembler?
I'm trying to analyse startup code of AArch64 processor.
At the very beginning of the code, there is
.org 0
.text

.globl _boot
.globl _vector_table

... 

.org 0
.section .vectors

...

I wonder followings:

which section expressions before .text directive belong to?

what is the role of .org directive before .text directive? why .org 0 appears again after first .org 0


I've read 'Using as' manual.. but I can't get it. I need some Usage examples of .org directive...
thank you in advance!

Initially, the .text section is active.  This is what .org applies to.  Then, the section is uselessly set to .text again.  Note that 0 is the defaut origin, so the .org directive doesn't do anything useful either.

Your answer helped me understand. Thank you!
